# Avoid compiling cpp files if header is not included

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino

In my C++ project (vscode 1.71.0, platformio core 6.1.4 home 3.4.3 under Ubuntu 22.04) I set up some `#define` to customize the features of my firmware:

common.h

```
// App features
#define ENABLE_RTC
#define ENABLE_IRRX
#define ENABLE_DDS
//#define ENABLE_PROXIMITY
```

Then, in my main.cpp:

```
#include "common.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

#ifdef ENABLE_DDS
#inclue "dds.h"
#endif

#ifdef ENABLE_PROXIMITY
#inclue "proxy.h"
#endif

...
```

Also below in the code there are `#ifdef` conditions to enable or disable the related part.
The problem is even if I don't include an header (like `proxy.h` in the example above) the compiler still tried to compile the cpp file:

```
Compiling .pio/build/myproject/src/dds.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/myproject/src/proximity.cpp.o
```

How to tell the compiler to NOT build the source files with no header included?

### EDIT

Not sure how to provide more information about the toolchain.
It's the default used by vscode+PlatformIO for ESP32.

In the configuration files I can see:

```
        "cStandard": "c99",
        "cppStandard": "c++11",
        "compilerPath": "/home/mark/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc",
        "compilerArgs": [
            "-mlongcalls",
            ""
        ]
```

Please, feel free to suggest me where to find further information you may need.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question.  Rather than `"How to tell the compiler to NOT build the source files with no header included?"`, the real question is: "why is the source file being recompiled even if it doesn't make use of an updated header?".  That being the case the real problem lies with your makefiles (or whatever build system you are using).  You need to provide more details of that.

Comment: @G.M. question update. Hoping this information is enough,

Answer (score 1):

Add `#ifdef/#endif` clauses in your .cpp like it's usually done for headers.
It will reduce the compilation to produce an empty `*.o` file.

In your `dds.cpp`:

```
#include "common.h"
#ifdef ENABLE_DDS
...
#endif //EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, it may work of course. But it's more a workaround than an actual answer to my question. I mean, the answer can also be: "there is no way to tell such a thing to the compiler".

Comment: @Mark It is the only reliable answer given the information you provided. If you used CMake you could use conditional compilation, but there is no info on what build system you use.